# Rails: Do which instance belongs a variable, which is defined in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I define an instance-variable in a Rails-controller like for example:

```
def new
    @article = Article.new
end
```

I know that I declare an instance-attribute there. But:
To which instance will @article become a member of?

How is it possible that it is accessible afterward in the according view without specifying an instance?

For example:

```
<%= @article.description %>
```

Actually I would expect something like `myInstance.article.description`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@article` is an instance variable of your controller class (presumably `ArticlesController` given your code snippet). When your controller renders a view, the Rails replicates the controller's instance variables automatically so that the view gains the same instance variables.